# A way to see what kernel function is being called before crashing?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want to see what kernel function is being called when doing something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {0};
    arr[3000] = 8; // I want to see what kernel function sends the SIGBUS
}
```

Is there a way to do it using gdb, or some other tool?

Comment: Well, you're not guaranteed to get a signal. It's undefined behaviour, so anything could happen, including nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure if this sequence of calls is arch specific, but for arm:

```
do_page_fault -> __do_user_fault -> force_sig_info.
```

You can't check through gdb cuz it is a kernel. Use dump_stack() / printk / ftrace kernel API if you want to investigate more.
By the way, - it is not obvious that this code will get exception signal...

Comment: While you shouldn't *count on* this crashing, it is rather likely to on today's systems.  If the stack grows downwards, the access far beyond the array's end end will probably be above the origin address of the stack and outside the page mapped for it, hence likely to trigger a fault unless some other page belonging to the process is mapped at that address.  If you print out some pointers and put in a sleep, you can go look at the page mappings for the process in /proc, when I do that I see a gap between the stack mapping and the next, perhaps put there to try to catch this kind of thing.